# Any way to make HTML disabled checkbox darker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm using javascript to disable a checkbox:

```
       $('#test').attr("disabled", "true");
```

but I'd like to make the background of the disabled checkbox darker, because as it is it's hard to tell that it is disabled. Is there any way to do this using HTML/CSS/JS>

Comment: In Firefox, the background-color of a disabled check-box is lighter than the bg-color of an enabled check-box. So, by making it darker, you'd make it *harder* to tell if it's disabled.

Answer (score 5):

Not easily. The way the checkbox is rendered is determined by the browser. You would have to replace it with a custom JavaScritpt based solution to give it a custom rendering, but that brings other problems.

What you *could* do though is make disabled checkboxes a bit more transparent:

```
  select[disabled] { opacity: .5 }
```

this works in IE >= 9 and all other major browsers.

Comment: not a solution, just an addition - http://jsfiddle.net/sbsCp/ because works in Webkit browsers only :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping the checkbox in a container `div`, and use `input:disabled` CSS rules like this: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BTaZ8/1/).

I have tested this in the latest Windows versions of Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

Comment: You can also use `input[disabled]` instead of `input:disabled` for backward-compatibility. http://jsfiddle.net/BTaZ8/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a CSS style for disabled input form elements like so:

```
input[disabled]{
 color:#666 !important; // Whatever styling here...
 opacity: .3;
}
```